# Do we need do something about tis reviewer - with image enhancements

Tags: discussion

For example this one
https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/163822

The images do not need enhancement, and don't look any different.  I am rejecting them, but others must be approving them, because the reviewer keeps doing a few every day.

Answer (score 9):

That change replaced the original full size images (1200x1600 pixels in a random sampling of the links) with the large thumbnails of each image (375x500 pixels for the same image), which means that they no longer overwhelm the page. It also added click-through links to the full size images.

This is a worthwhile edit because it makes each image more manageable, especially on mobile devices which may not have high resolution screens.

It also reduces the amount of data that must be downloaded to view the page, another benefit for mobile devices which often have data caps, or for people with slow internet connections.

Please approve edits like this in future.

Comment: Hi @RohitGupta! I'm the editor in question! The edits are primarily to reduce bandwidth and load times. Some of the images can be as large as 4000x3000, and sometimes may even exceed the SE limit of 2Mb if they used their own personal image links. Please see the [SE Thumbnail Guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow/108821#108821) to get details of what I'm doing.