# Do I need to do anything about a reviewer that consistently rejects my edits?

Tags: discussion

Follow-up to [Do we need do something about tis reviewer - with image enhancements](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/do-we-need-do-something-about-tis-reviewer-with-image-enhancements)

I've been adding Imgur thumbnail resize options to a lot of the oversized pictures, and a particular reviewer doesn't seem to understand it and just rejects all of them. That hasn't deterred the other reviewers from approval though, so they get approved in the end.

Does this affect me in any way?

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for pointing this out. If there were any edits that were rejected because of this bad review let me know. The mods have taken steps to address this specific reviewer's history. If you see bad reviews from this or other users again, let us know.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit I've been skeptical about whether some of the image enhancements actually were a significant improvement, and have voted a few down. Stopped doing that, I think, when the policy justifying it started appearing in the edit reasons. I'm still skeptical about some cases but I'll just skip them rather than actively disagreeing.

If SE wants images normalized and sharpened (which is what these changes seem to be doing), I'd be happier to see it run as a batch process on SE's end of the wire, perhaps automatically upon submission. But if volunteers are all they can get, I'll try not to stand in the way.

Comment: I think this uniquely affects DIY in that we have people uploading a lot of images that are not skilled at image manipulation. On sites like Photography and UX, they would have a lot of images but they're expected to grasp that having an inline 4000x3000 sized image doesn't help anyone. I suspect it'll be hard to justify the risk of changing upload process that affects the entire site, but the end result is that some questions load noticeably slower simply because they're loading back-to-back 2Mb pictures instead of a 100kb thumbnail. I do perform analysis with the developer console.

Comment: I don't really have problems with some rejections because it helps me understand what makes sense and what doesn't, and approvers are also volunteers, so the rejections are taken into consideration and I've tuned down the volume. This question really was due to very consistent rejection even when fully justified, such as posts containing multiple oversized images.

Comment: I don't know that I would realize images were "oversized", especially since SE has rejected my attempts to post images straight off the phone and insisted I scale them down. 

... Personally I think SE ought to be smart enough to do for users, since not all users know how. That would also remove the need for you to go through doing this manually.

(I'm on a fast connection; I haven't noticed speed issues. If they're there, fixing them makes sense, but fix the system, not just the data, or the problem will continue to occur.)

Comment: I think as long as SE sticks with imgur they are basically pushing images to a second-class, "we don't care about them enough to do much with them" mode. Which is their choice. But it really wouldn't be all that hard for them to roll their own image storage system which would include automatic handling of large images (e.g., currently > 2 Meg.) on upload, easier manipulation of images (rotate, resize, etc.) and other features. They just don't care. Or at least not much. Most of the larger sites are programming or computer support related and images are less critical than in things like DIY.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think these edits are helpful, for many reasons:

- Having the full-resolution image directly in the post is beneficial. Browsers generally make it pretty easy to zoom in on scaled-down large images to see the fine details. In my opinion it's worthwhile to be able to zoom in and see the fine details directly on the post page, instead of being forced to open every image in a new tab.
- The SE page styling gives no indication when a smaller image is linked to a larger version. Viewers may not realize there is a larger version to click-through to.
- Large image dimensions aren't a problem - the page styling limits image width, so large images don't break the page layout.
- I've seen too many of this kind of edit accidentally lose some of the pictures in the shuffle.
- It's 2023. An extra megabyte or two is not a lot of data today. The bare minimum connection speed that can be called "broadband" in the U.S. is 25Mbps (and we're not exactly cutting-edge). 25Mbps transfers a megabyte in less than a third of a second.
- An extra megabyte or two isn't a massive increase over the baseline size of an SE question page load. A random DIY question I picked to check (with no images) involves 87 requests to 13 domains, resulting in 6.80 MB loaded (3.22 MB transferred over the wire).

Comment: People viewing on phones with limited data plans (or in poor service ares with slow data, even with "unlimited" data) probably don't share your opinion about size of image. A preview image allows a fast assesment of "I need to see more or am interested in seing more" .vs. "nothing here of interest to see." Choosing to vandalize edits because you don't care for the policy is...annoying.